# Conditionally create bean if Map of properties is not empty with SpEL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I have a class with a method that is periodically invoked with the `@Scheduled` annotation. The method does some bulk operations on a given set of properties.
If there are no properties set, I don't need the scheduled method invocation nor the instantiated class. Therefore, I've added this `SpEL` expression to check whether the properties are set:

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnExpression("#(T(java.util.Map)('${myproperties.people:{:}}')).size() > 0")
public class PeopleService { ... }
```

Example values in the `application.yml` could be:

```
myproperties:
  people:
    uuid1:
      name: Mark
      age: 32
    uuid2:
      name: Jeff
      age: 36
```

Unfortunately I get this error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [#(T(java.util.Map)('{:}')).size() > 0] @1: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lparen(()'
```

Note that I came up with `{:}` for an empty map as default value here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-inline-maps

If I use this SpEL, I get the following error: `"#(T(java.util.Map)(${myproperties.people:})).size() > 0"`

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [#(T(java.util.Map)()).size() > 0] @1: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lparen(()'
```

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This annotation:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#(T(java.util.Map)('${myproperties.people:{:}}')).size() > 0")
```

Doesn't work because Spring read LITERALLY all your properties like that:

- myproperties.people.uuid1.name=Mark
- myproperties.people.uuid1.age=32
- myproperties.people.uuid2.name=Jeff
- myproperties.people.uuid2.age=36

If you check Spring Boot documentation, [this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html#:%7E:text=This%20condition%20cannot%20be%20reliably%20used%20for%20matching%20collection%20properties.%20For%20example%2C%20in%20the%20following%20configuration%2C%20the%20condition%20matches%20if%20spring.example.values%20is%20present%20in%20the%20Environment%20but%20does%20not%20match%20if%20spring.example.values%5B0%5D%20is%20present.) explains that "the condition matches if spring.example.values is present in the Environment but does not match if spring.example.values[0] is present.".

So for Spring, property "myproperties.people" just doesn't exist. On the same page, they explain that "it is better to use a custom condition for such cases."

A workaround is to define a property class (but it's not wasted, because you will use this class to parse your yaml as a map):

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myproperties")
public class MyPeopleProperties {
    
    private Map<String, String> people;

    public Map<String, String> getPeople() {
        return people;
    }

    public void setPeople(Map<String, String> people) {
        this.people = people;
    }

}
```

And on your main class:

```
...
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;
...

@Service
@Conditional(PeopleService.PeopleServiceCondition.class)
public class PeopleService { 

    ... 

    public static class PeopleServiceCondition implements Condition {

        @Override
        public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
            MyPeopleProperties config = Binder.get(context.getEnvironment())
                    .bind("myproperties", MyPeopleProperties.class).orElse(null);
            return config != null && config.getPeople() != null && !config.getPeople().isEmpty();
        }

    }

}
```

So `myproperties.people` will be bound as map, then we check if this map exists on the bean declaration condition.

Answer (score 0):

Circling back around to the SpEL implementation, you actually *can* do it entirely in SpEL but it's really ugly:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression(
    "(" +
        "T(org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder)" +
        ".get(environment)" +
        ".bind('myproperties.people', T(java.util.Map))" +
        ".orElse(null)" +
        "?.size()" +
        "?: 0" +
    ") > 0"
)
```

This will work even for deeply-nested config subtrees - the simplistic binding to the `Map` class just creates a bunch of denormalized/flattened `<String,String>` entries with keys like `uuid1.name`.  That means that if you are just testing for the existence of *any* sub-tree elements under the `myproperties.people` namespace, the above will work fine.  It is, in effect, exactly what you probably would have meant when writing `@ConditionalOnProperty("myproperties.people")`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind squeezing myproperties.people into a single property:

```
myproperties:
    people: "{key1:'value1',key2:'value2'}
```

You can do this:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#(T(java.util.Map)('${myproperties.people:T(java.util.Collections).EMPTY_MAP}')).size() > 0")
```